# Visual Basic Dynamically Create and Erase Controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I use *Visual Basic* in Visual Studio 2015  and i am trying when i click on a StripMenu to appear me some TextBoxes and Buttons.
After another click in Stripmenu i want to erase them and add new one.
My problem is in **Erase** (delete or clear my buttons and textboxes) controls  from my surface.
I try to do it use **Button.Visible =True (or False)** but it's not seems to be really helpful in a big amount of controls.

```
Private Sub ClassAToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClassAToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Label1.Text = "Sum A class Students: "

    Dim btnA As Button = New Button
    btnA.Location = New Point(420, 180)
    btnA.Name = "Btn1"
    btnA.Text = "OK"
    btnA.Visible = True
    Me.Controls.Add(btnA)
    AddHandler btnA.Click, AddressOf button
End Sub

Private Sub button()
    'What my Button does.
End Sub
```

I create dynamically through this code my Button but if i want to go in another Menu option i want to erase this button to add again my new controls (such us new buttons labels etc).

Comment: Don't tag every VB language known to man.

Comment: Can you summarise this into a question? You should probably add some source code as well. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I post my code to help you understand my question.

Comment: If you're trying to get rid of the controls, use [Button.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) to clean it up. Don't forget to remove the handler you added.

Comment: I tried to do it with btnA.Dispose() but i received this error BC30451 and its told me that i have an issue with accesimbility in btnA (My Button).

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is out of scope since you declared it in the menu's click method.  You would have to use the Find method to get back the reference to the control you created:

```vb
Dim btn = Me.Controls.Find("Btn1", True).FirstOrDefault()
If btn IsNot Nothing Then
  btn.Dispose()
End If
```

If you are trying to replace the contents of a panel with a new "screen" on your menu click, you can try code like this:

```vb
While Panel1.Controls.Count > 0
  Panel1.Controls(0).Dispose()
End While

Dim newControl As New UserControl1
newControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Panel1.Controls.Add(newControl)
```

Comment: @NikosKoutantos Not sure what that means.  Your question was regarding disposing dynamically created controls, so I tried to show you that.  If you have a lot of controls you are doing this with, you should be creating UserControls that house the collection of controls, and you would just add and dispose of that.

Comment: I am sorry but this method where in my code i will use it to take results, because i am looking for a function that clear my form from all the controls and i hope that the next event will create it again.Thank's for your time.

Comment: When i click my StripMenu i want to appear a different surface in the same form, i dont want to create a new form.That's why i am trying to delete all controls and the new event(in my case a new StripMenu Click) create the new controls.

Comment: @NikosKoutantos Then create these screens in a UserControl and just show and dispose of the UserControl as needed.

Comment: I actually want to make a software with multiple pages.If i click in my StripMenu appear a page if i click another one appear another page.

Comment: @NikosKoutantos I tried updating the answer with a simple example.

Comment: My problem actually is that when i use panels i need to make my panel visible and all the  others invisible.And that's not pretty useful if i have a number of 9 panels for example, that's why i am asking you another way to do it.